# VB.net How can i set an icon for my own file extension

Tags: vb.net, winforms

i want to set icon to all files with Extension: ".fEx", also i want that the file will open with my application, how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a VB.NET question, but you can achieve what you want by coding in VB.NET.

basically you have to set the required registry values to associate the filetype and tell it what application will opejn it by default

Have a look at [this code project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18594/File-Association-in-VB-NET) - it explains everything you should need to know.

Answer (score 2):

In order to do that you need to create a DefaultIcon key for your extension under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT then just set the value to @="icon path"

This should be the location you need to insert the path of the icon you will want to use.

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.fEx\DefaultIcon

Answer (score 0):

This article is written for C#, but VB.NET is close enough that you should be able to write nearly identical code to accomplish what you want.
[C#: Set File Type Association](http://mel-green.com/2009/04/c-set-file-type-association/)

Answer (score 0):

You must set the appropriate registry entries.

- [Set the file association in VB.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18594/File-Association-in-VB-NET)